# I can't insert images to articles

Tags: media, 8

I installed Drupal 8 today, the release candidate 3. I had not done any modifications to it. When I edit my first article, I can't insert images. I clicked on the image button, but it keeps loading forever. I saw other people clicking the image button and a pop-up appearing.

Do I have to install a module?

[image]

Comment: press f12, switch to console tab, then click on that image button and see if there are any errors on the console.

Comment: Try using a different web browser and see what happens.

Comment: When I click the image button, the console says " uncaught AjaxError, An Ajax HTTP error occured Debugging information follows. Path: /editor/dialog/image/full_html" @IvanJaros

Comment: I used both google chrome and firefox, but still can't insert images.@NoSssweat

Comment: I have RC2, no problems here. I will update later, when I have some time, to RC3 and let you know if it's just you or if it's an RC3 bug.

Comment: check watchdog entries.

Comment: I've installed Drupal 8.0.6 and have the exact same problem. Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer. Nothing in the status report, error log on server, etc. Just in the browser's console. Without the console you don't even know that something went wrong. Just that "Loading..." stays there and nothing happens.

Comment: Solved it. It was the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

**My solution was simple: After updating Drupal8, ensure you run any pending scripts!** Otherwise you will not be able to do certain things with your Drupal8 site.
Yesterday I updated my Drupal from some ancient version to the latest stable Drupal8. I noticed I can't add images [the forever loading problem], and I'm just a home user not behind a fancy firewall. After updating 13 pending scripts, everything was fine.
I'm not a very technical person, but I wanted to share my solution because no one else had shared this.
My website is ontu.org and thus the settings page for me was here:
http://ontu.org/admin/reports/status

Change that URL to your site and you'll quickly go to your settings page. There may be multiple issues reported on that page, so notice everything on there.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of bugs fixed with dialogs in general and the Text Editor dialogs in particular during the RC phase of Drupal 8. It's definitely been working fine ever since Drupal 8.0.0.

Comment: I've installed Drupal 8.0.6 and have the exact same problem. Firefox, Google Chrome, Internet Explorer. Nothing in the status report, error log on server, etc. Just in the browser's console. Without the console you don't even know that something went wrong. Just that "Loading..." stays there and nothing happens.

Comment: Solved it. It was the firewall.

Comment: Oh haha. I wonder what was triggering the firewall then. Which firewall? In any case a crappy one.

Comment: I don't have any specifics. It's the new firewall in our company. There's a proxy that filters all unknown HTTP response header entries. I could use HTTPS only, until the firewall gets updated to filters that, too. :-(

Comment: The firewall is WatchGuard. And this seems to filter everything on default. Even the CORS headers that are needed to use external Google fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your firewall doesn't filter too many HTTP response header lines. They are used to validate the Ajax response.

```
X-Drupal-Ajax-Token: 1
```

etc.

It's a known bug: https://www.drupal.org/node/2580191